# Адаптивный макет в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, responsive, layout

На форме есть два verticalLayout и один horizontalLayout, нужно сделать их адаптивными к размеру окна, то есть при изменении его размеров данные элементы должны пропорционально расширяться или сужаться до определённых значений. Пробовал поместить все эти виджеты в gridLayout, но размеры не изменялись. Возможно ли реализовать такую адаптивность в Qt Designer? Или необходимо делать это программно?

Comment: Конечно можно прямо в Дизайнере. Выбираете нужный виджет и в верхнем меню, в режиме Дизайнера, выбираете нужный лейаут

Comment: @AlexanderChernin к сожалению нет возможности сделать это в конструкторе форм.

Comment: @jNX, это можно сделать в конструкторе форм. Насколько я помню если на пустом окне кликнуть на три линии (вертикальные или горизонтальные), то компоновщик станет компоновщиком текущего окна: https://build-system.fman.io/static/public/img/qt-designer-windows.png . В ui компоновщик будет внутри виджета: https://github.com/gil9red/QRCodeGenerator/blob/4b104d24a98840ed51b6a4134844dfcae511e4b7/mainwindow.ui#L17

Comment: @gil9red во правы , Я как то даже не знал о такой возможности. Специально создал проект и попробовал все. Об верхнем меню как то даже не подумал\не так понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Режим дизайнера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираете необходимый виджет и лейаут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забавно, что сам до задания вопроса пробовал компоновку в этом меню, но поочерёдно выбирал все лейауты, из-за чего адаптивности не было. Нужно было применить компоновку на центральном виджете.

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы добиться такого эффекта необходимо дописать 3 строчки кода. Первое что вам необходимо сделать это создать VboxLayout в окне mainwindow в дизайнере и растянуть его побольше для удобства. Далее устанавливаете этот Layout как центр widget. Для этого в конструкторе mainwindow добавляете следующее:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->setLayout(ui->verticalLayout);//verticalLayout имя переменной в ui форме
setCentralWidget(widget);
```

После этого в этот Layout накидываете вертикальный и горизонтальный Layout, после чего уже наполняете сами Layout.

Comment: могу залить на гитхаб кусок кода который делает как раз то что вам нужно))